# Chart js bar with the highest value is a different color among the rest - React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a chart for Peak Hours and I want the hour with the highest value to be of a different color, how do I do that? For example, in the data array, ideally the one that should have a different bar color would be the one with the value "12".  Currently I've only set one color in the `data.datasets.backgroundColor` and I'm not sure how to add a `backgroundColor` conditionally. I'm using React so I've installed `chartjs` in my project. Ideally it should look something like [image]

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ padding: "0 15px" }}
        className="chart"
      >
        <div>
          <span>1 PM usually busy</span>
        </div>

        <Bar
          height={145}
          responsive={false}
          data={{
            labels: [
              "00",
              "",
              "",
              "03",
              "",
              "",
              "06",
              " ",
              "",
              "09",
              "",
              "",
              "12",
              "",
              "",
              "15",
              "",
              "",
              "18",
              " ",
              "",
              "21",
              " ",
              "",
              "24",
            ],
            fontSize: 1,

            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Time",
                data: [
                  2,
                  0,
                  3,
                  4,
                  5,
                  8,
                  7,
                  8,
                  9,
                  10,
                  11,
                  12,
                  11,
                  10,
                  9,
                  6,
                  7,
                  8,
                  7,
                  5,
                  4,
                  3,
                  2,
                  8,
                ],
                backgroundColor: ["#33AF4F"],
                borderWidth: 0,
              },
            ],
          }}
          options={{
            barThickness: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
           

            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: false,
               
                labels: {
                  fontSize: 9,
                  boxWidth: 5,
                  usePointStyle: true,
                },
              },
             
            },
            scales: {
              x: {
                ticks: {
                  font: {
                    size: 10,
                  },
                },
                stacked: true,
                grid: {
                  display: false,
                },
              },
              y: {
                ticks: {
                  display: false,
                },
                stacked: true,

                grid: {
                  borderDash: [2, 3],
                  color: "#bdbdbd",
                },
              },
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function giving conditional array of colors for in the place of `backgroundColor: ["#33AF4F"]`

taking into consideration that you want highest value with different color create this function before rendering component.

```
function getBgColors() {
  var array  = [2,0,3,4,5,8,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,10,9,6,7,8,7,5,4,3,2,8];
  var maxValue = Math.max.apply(this, array);

  var bg = array.map(a => a === maxValue ? "#0f7d28" : "#33AF4F");
  return bg;
}
```

and call this function at `backgroundColor: getBgColors()`